# How do I run Nightwatch.js tests in Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, tfs, nightwatch.js

I would like to implement CI/CD with UI tests I've written to automatically run my Nightwatch.js test on a nightly basis. I've tried copying my files to a workspace in jenkins and running them. I've tried using TFS as a version control system to see if we could get it to run that way. The problem I keep running into (see attached) is that when I run locally the chrome browser opens and runs the tests just fine. In Jenkins, however, It says that it can't find the element. I've researched how to run chrome headlessly but I still get the same error when I add the --headless tag to my nightwatch.json config file. Bottom line, How can I get Nightwatch.js tests to run on a nightly schedule? (preferably in jenkins)

Tried running tests from tfs source control
tried running tests from local tests copied to jenkins workspace.
tried running headless tests (locally works, Jenkins does not)https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Here is my nightwatch.json file.

```
{
    "src_folders" : ["tests"],
    "output_folder" : "reports/XMLReports",
    "custom_commands_path" : "",
    "custom_assertions_path" : "",
    "page_objects_path" : "dealer",
    "globals_path" : "",
    "test_workers": false,
    "selenium": {
      "cli_args": {
        "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "node_modules/.bin/chromedriver.cmd",
        "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "node_modules/.bin/geckodriver.cmd",
        "webdriver.edge.driver" : "node_modules/.bin/edgedriver.cmd"
    },
    "log_path": "",
    "port": 4460,
    "server_path": "lib/drivers/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar",
    "start_process": true
  },

    "test_settings" : {
      "chrome" : {
        "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
        "selenium_port"  : 4460,
        "selenium_host"  : "127.0.0.1",
        "silent": true,
        "screenshots" : {
          "enabled" : false,
          "path" : "screenshots/Chrome/"
        },
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "chromeOptions":{
                "args": [
                  "disable-web-security",
                  "ignore-certificate-errors",
                  "--test-type",
                  "--disable-gpu",
                  "--headless",
                  "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
                ]
            }          
        }
      },

      "edge" : {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I would expect my tests to run in jenkins normally and give me a detailed report if it passed or failed in the ui.[image: Error received from Jenkins]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the .windowMaximize() was causing my tests to hang and fail in Jenkins.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @Jackson was it just the .windowMaximize() problem?